# Android Tensorflow using Tango Services

Tags: google-project-tango

I am wondering if anybody has tried Android Tensorflow by using Google Tango Services (For example inside a callback like onFrameAvailable or onPointCloudAvailable. I am looking for any possibility integrating Tensorflow (for example Classify module) with a Google Tango project, where I cannot access the camera by using Android API. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what data you want for your TensorFlow project.

Since Tango works of getting frame and point cloud data as fast as possible, it doesn't save it to memory as it would fill a GB of data in no time. This being said, the next question is did you want to try running TensorFlow right on the device or another machine remotely. If you want to run it on the device then I feel that is more than what a phone can handle in terms of processing with current technology.

If you want to send it off to another machine again there is the question of trying to get results real-time or not. If you don't need real-time then I would suggest just writing all the data to a file or saving the data in a way the 3D Reconstruction API does already for you. If you need quick data sent back and forth I know of this [NDK Websocket single library file](https://github.com/sjfricke/Android-NDK-WebSocket) which can send data at a reasonable rate and also get a response back with what TensorFlow finds whenever you need to send something back. This could be way better optimized with some more clever TCP/UDP networking tricks, but I feel this idea in a whole is quite the undertaking if you are mainly focused on the TensorFlow part itself